# connect embedded derby database with struts application

Tags: struts2, derby

i have an embedded derby database "end_user" and i want to pre-populate the table "user" with a few records before accessing it via a struts2 application. For this, i need to set the url of the database, but i don't know what url to set. the struts application is deployed as a war in apache-tomcat/webapps.

I have currently tried this:

```
jdbc:derby:1527/
```

But this does not seem to help in any way. I even tried hardcoding the path of the db i created (ie. C:\apache-tomcat\end_user) and even that did not help

what to do?

Comment: Embedded database requires space on hard drive to store their images, where do you want to mount that space.

Comment: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/getstart/

Comment: the database is to be stored in the apache-tomcat/webapp directory, where my struts2 application war is also hosted.