# pre-populate embedded database with struts2 application

Tags: struts2, derby

i have a **Struts2** application with an embedded **Derby database**. i want to export the database along with the war of the application itself, along with the tables and the data. my purpose is that the database which will be created, should be pre-populated with the default data.

For the table and data, i have an sql file:

```
 CREATE TABLE DEPT (
    DEPTNO              NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    DNAME               VARCHAR2(14),
    LOC                 VARCHAR2(13),
    CONSTRAINT DEPT_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (DEPTNO));

    INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
    INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
    INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
    INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');
```

any way i can accomplish that? will the database still have write access or will it be read-only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [connect embedded derby database with struts application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613866/connect-embedded-derby-database-with-struts-application)

Comment: If you're trying to figure out how to run your script of SQL statements from your program see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740926/execute-db-statements-from-file